# How can I add a horizontal line in php after some text?

Tags: php, html, css, line

I do know how to add horizontal line in html by using `<hr>` but I am not sure how to do in php.

My code:

```
  echo '<div class="grid">';
            echo '<p>' .  $row["title"] . '</p>';
            
            echo '</div>';
```

I want a line here like (________________) on the website after the `$row["title"]`

I tried doing this:

echo `<hr style="width:50%; text-align:left;margin-left:0">`;

But it doesn't seem to work. How can I add the horizontal line? Also, I would like to style it with a color, so something like a colored horizontal line such as yellow or any color?

Comment: But it doesn't seem to work... What exactly does that do? My personal guess is that you forgot to escape quotes in style properly. What happens if you add only `echo <hr />;` to the code and style it via CSS?

Comment: This question need more details and a picture like it supposed to be. by the way my response should work.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for not being too clear. Yeah, that works as suggested in comment and the answer and I can style using css. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the changes below

Change this:

```
echo '<div class="grid">';
echo '<p>' .  $row["title"] . '</p>';
echo '</div>';
```

To this:

```
echo '<div class="grid">' . '<p>' .  $row["title"] . '</p>' . '</div>';
echo '<hr/>';
```

This should work depend on your parent container width.
More how to use this break you can find here: [HTML <hr> Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hr.asp)